# Group Columns with Left Outer Joins involved

Tags: sql

Im trying to group/summarize all my information data together but I can't get me head around it.

Is it because I have Inner joins?

```
SELECT DISTINCT jh."job-date",jh."company", jh."job-dept", jh."job-route", rc.COSTS, rh.SALES, rh.SALES - rc.COSTS as PROFIT
FROM MSN.PUB."job-hdr" jh 

left outer join
(select rh."rec-id", SUM(rh."base-sales-value") as SALES
  from MSN.PUB."rec-chg" rh
  group by rh."rec-id") rh
 on jh."job-id" = rh."rec-id" 

left outer join
 (select rc."rec-id", SUM(rc."base-cost-value") as COSTS
  from MSN.PUB."rec-cost" rc
  group by rc."rec-id") rc
 on jh."job-id" = rc."rec-id"

WHERE
  jh."job-status" <> 'D' and
  jh."job-date" between '2012-04-01' and '2013-03-31'
 Group by jh."job-route", jh."company", jh."job-dept",jh."job-date", rc."COSTS", rh."SALES"
```

This is the results i'm getting out.

job-date  company job-dept job-route COSTS SALES    PROFIT

2012-04-01  03  AII IBD 793.48  820.53  27.05

2012-04-01  03  AII ICH 20.87   43.35   22.48

2012-04-01  03  AII ICH 130.97  143.64  12.67

2012-04-01  03  AII ICH 291.52  363.63  72.11

2012-04-01  03  AII ICH 384.90  437.44  52.54

I need them summariszed so I don't have so many lines of data?

Comment: Do you need to get an aggregate value, like the sum or average of one or more columns?

Comment: I just need the Total Cost, Sales & Profit for each Date, Company, Jobdept and Job route

Comment: Also, you don't have inner joins anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT jh."job-date",jh."company", jh."job-dept", jh."job-route",
       sum(rc.COSTS) as COSTS,
       sum(rh.SALES) as SALES, sum(rh.SALES - rc.COSTS) as PROFIT
FROM MSN.PUB."job-hdr" jh left outer join
     (select rh."rec-id", SUM(rh."base-sales-value") as SALES
      from MSN.PUB."rec-chg" rh
      group by rh."rec-id"
     ) rh
     on jh."job-id" = rh."rec-id" left outer join
     (select rc."rec-id", SUM(rc."base-cost-value") as COSTS
      from MSN.PUB."rec-cost" rc
      group by rc."rec-id"
     ) rc
     on jh."job-id" = rc."rec-id"
WHERE jh."job-status" <> 'D' and
      jh."job-date" between '2012-04-01' and '2013-03-31'
Group by jh."job-route", jh."company", jh."job-dept", jh."job-date";
```

I removed `COSTS` and `SALES` from the `group by` and added aggregation functions in the `select`.